# retrieving float from tkinter Entry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, floating-point, tkinter-entry

I know similar questions have been asked but I can't make the code work.
I have tried many things with no success.

What I am trying to do is to get the float values inputted by the user in an Entry box to then do some mathematical operations in the function centroid(kind, a,b,c,d,e,f).
For this instance, I have set c,d,e,f to 0.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me a hand with this.
Thanks

```
def show_dimension_boxes(section):

    global img
    
    ask_dimensions = Label(sections_frame,text='Enter Dimensions', font=5).place(x=200,y=80)
        
    if section == 'rectangular':
            
        labelA = Label(text='a', font=5).place(x=200, y=120)
        labelB = Label(text='b', font=5).place(x=200, y=160)
        
        EntryA = Entry(root)
        EntryB = Entry(root)
                
        a = float(EntryA.get())
        b = float(EntryB.get())
        c = 0
        d = 0
        e = 0
        f = 0
        
        entrya = EntryA.place(x=250, y=120)
        entryb = EntryB.place(x=250, y=160)
        
        img = Image.open('rectangular.gif')
        img = img.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        image = Label(root, image=img)
        image.place(x=260, y=200)
        
        get_dimensions = Button(root, text='Calculate', command=lambda: centroid(section, a, b, c, d, e, f)).pack()
```

Comment: You're getting the value about a millisecond after creating the entry widgets. You need to wait to get the values after the user has a chance to see and interact with the GUI.

Comment: Solved! I just called a new function to get the values and did a try/except to convert them to floats